# Android AWS S3 Access Denied - Uploading plain text to Bucket on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, bucket

I want to upload a txt file to an Amazon bucket. I have the credentials (both keys) and can successfully retrieve the folder structure found in the bucket. However, I was unable to upload a file to any of the folders, nor in the root of the path.

The error I get is **AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XR5YENBX1E3SQH20)**.

[These are the policies established for this bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b6r4.png)

Using this method below, I manage to get the structure of the folders (each folder name and subfolders):

```
val result: ListObjectsV2Result =
s3Client.listObjectsV2(AWSCredentials.BUCKET_NAME)
val objects = result.objectSummaries

for (os in objects) {
println(os.key)
}
```

The result is:

```
I/System.out: 2101/
I/System.out: 2101/Entrada/
I/System.out: 2101/Salida/
I/System.out: 2301/
I/System.out: 2301/Entrada/
I/System.out: 2301/Salida/
```

But when I use this method below to upload the plain text file, I get the error mentioned above:

`val request = PutObjectRequest( AWSCredentials.BUCKET_NAME, "2301/Entrada/maestro.txt", exampleFile )   s3Client.putObject(request)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I missed to add the configuration for server-side encryption (SSE-S3).

```
val objectMetadata = ObjectMetadata()
objectMetadata.contentLength = exampleFile.contentLength!!
objectMetadata.sseAlgorithm = ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION

val request = PutObjectRequest(AWSCredentials.BUCKET_NAME,
                                "2301/Entrada/maestro.txt",
                                exampleFile.decodeToString().byteInputStream(),
                                objectMetadata)
s3Client.putObject(request)
```